# Piecewise linear approximation of uniformly continuous function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ be uniformly continuous. I was wondering if there was a standard way to uniformly approximate $f$ with continuous piecewise linear functions. These functions would be of the form $g:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$, where there are disjoint sets $\{A_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ such that $\mathbb{R}^n=\cup_{i=1}^\infty A_i$ and $g(x)=\langle c_i,x\rangle + b_i$ for $x\in A_i$.

I was thinking of constructing a grid in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and evaluating $f$ at the vertices of this grid. If I could find a continuous piecewise linear function $g$ that agrees with the values of $f$ at these vertices, then I can make the grid arbitrarily fine to construct a sequence of continuous piecewise linear functions $\{f_j\}_{i=1}^\infty$ that uniformly converges to $f$. Any further hints on this problem would help. Thank you!

Comment: In $n=1$ this works. But for $n>1$, the choice of grid matters. For example in $\mathbb{R^2}$ if you choose the square grid then you have four conditions but the linear polynomial has only 3 coefficients. So your system is overdetermined. Maybe with triangles it could work. I'll refrain from asserting certainty on this matter. Side note: In bilinear interpolation you actually use quadratic polynomials (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation).

Comment: @Parthiv Basu Thank you for your response. Triangles would work in $\mathbb{R}^2$ if we break up each square of a grid into two triangles, so maybe there is a generalization of this method in higher dimensions. We could maybe break up each cube into sets $A_i$, where each $A_i$ can be fit with a linear function at the vertices $A_i$ and the cube share. I will do some research on bilinear interpolation.

Comment: @Charuvinda Hi. I was asking myself the same (if I can define a sequence of piecewise linear functions converging uniformly to a continuous function) question lately and stumbled upon this post. Have you found an answer in the meantime?

Comment: @DavideF. I am still stuck on this problem. If I ever find an answer, I will be sure to post it on this thread.